# Do I Need a Visa for changing the airports in Turkey?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, turkey, turkish-airlines

I have an Indian Passport and am travelling from Berlin to Dubai with Turkish airlines and have to change the airports in turkey. Do I need a visa for that?

Answer (score 4):

You are entering the country so yes you need a visa, but. Turkey has an eVisa. Are you eligible? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Turkey#Conditional_e-Visa) has you covered:

> Citizens of these countries and territories are also eligible under certain conditions to apply for a single entry e-Visa on which they can stay for up to 30 days

India is included.

Now let's see the conditions:

> All citizens except for the citizens of Gabon and Zambia, must hold a valid visa or residence from one of the following countries Schengen Countries, USA, UK or Ireland (except electronic visas).

If you are coming from Germany you surely have a Schengen visa.

> All citizens except for the citizens of Afghanistan, Bangladesh, Egypt, India,

OK I cut this off because you are a citizen of India it doesn't apply

> Must hold a hotel reservation and adequate financial means (US$50 per day)

Well, you are spending 0 days.

So: go ahead and apply for an [eVisa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/).